# Working on hw for Java class. Keep getting reached end of file while parsing error

Tags: java

//Here is my code I feel like I am missing a {or} somewhere but I can't tell where

```
public class Chapter2ProgramChallenge
 {

    public static void main(String[] args);
    {

        int customers;
            customers= 12467;   

            {

                System.out.println("The number of"+" people who have "+
                    "more than one " +"energy drink per week is"+" "+ customers*0.14 );

    }

    {
        System.out.println("Of those "+(customers*0.14)+"people"+
            (customers*0.14)*.64+"of them prefer "+"citrus drinks");
    }
```

Comment: You have a semicolon after `main` method definition, apart from other errors involving closing brackets (})...

Comment: "Keep getting reached end of file while parsing error." What file? What parsing? You have nothing remotely file-related in the code you've posted.

Comment: Lining up your braces in the same column in your source code file will help you visually match your braces.

Answer (score 4):

just get rid of `;`

```
public static void main(String[] args);
```

change this to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Also as mentioned by others in the comments, you may need to check your braces.

Comment: I tried that and it then gave me a whole new list of errors, including that is was expecting a ;

Comment: try checking the brackets as i had mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Although I see nothing "file" or "parsing" related in the code you have posted (as is in your title), I do see these three problems:

As stated by others, the semi-colon at the end of your function signature

```
public static void main(String[] args);
```

means your main function does *nothing*. Remove the semi-colon.

Second, these two blocks shouldn't be blocks at all:

```
        {

            System.out.println("The number of"+" people who have "+
                "more than one " +"energy drink per week is"+" "+ customers*0.14 );

}

{
    System.out.println("Of those "+(customers*0.14)+"people"+
        (customers*0.14)*.64+"of them prefer "+"citrus drinks");
}
```

Change them to this

```
System.out.println("The number of"+" people who have "+
   "more than one " +"energy drink per week is"+" "+ customers*0.14 );
System.out.println("Of those "+(customers*0.14)+"people"+
        (customers*0.14)*.64+"of them prefer "+"citrus drinks");
```

Beyond this, however, you'll have to provide more information before we can help you further.